# javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 2

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, client

I am trying to establish a TLS secured (with client authentication) connection over the XMPP protocol.  I am using the standard port rather than dedicated SSL port, which apparently is deprecated.  The startTLS process never completes the handshake.

I am receiving:
**javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 2**

Excerpts from debug show that my client receives an unexpected message from server. The CertificateRequest is sent from server but CA list is empty.

Are there very many things that can cause this handshake violoation (2)?  What might cause the server not to send the acceptable authorities which are configured in its truststore?

Thanks for any insight.

UPDATED:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@ PROTOTYPE: TLS client authentication XMPP connection. @@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
USER: 111111
OS:   Windows 7
Java: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Loading trusted authorities from trust store...
adding as trusted cert:
...(trimmed)

Loading credentials from key store...
***
found key for : Signing Certificate - John K. Doe
chain [0] = [
...(trimmed)
***
Initializing SSL context for TLS...
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@ PROTOTYPE: Built XMPP connection configuration. @@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Connection instantiated.
10:17:24 AM SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='steerage.org' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
10:17:24 AM RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="steerage.org" id="e7e393bd" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"><stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"><required/></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>EXTERNAL</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
10:17:24 AM SENT (0): <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'></starttls>
10:17:24 AM RECV (0): <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1433793908 bytes = { 4, 180, 17, 97, 147, 6, 68, 124, 234, 40, 155, 145, 132, 27, 164, 29, 175, 239, 139, 23, 14, 133, 162, 215, 44, 220, 241, 2 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=steerage.org]
***
Smack Packet Reader (0), WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 239
Smack Packet Reader (0), READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 3708
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1433793908 bytes = { 238, 60, 108, 5, 104, 190, 219, 147, 215, 187, 195, 89, 114, 224, 165, 213, 141, 48, 112, 176, 129, 42, 78, 190, 196, 119, 143, 101 }
Session ID:  {85, 118, 245, 116, 90, 98, 141, 24, 47, 246, 162, 187, 92, 255, 11, 153, 45, 237, 178, 52, 9, 196, 116, 50, 61, 190, 48, 63, 26, 70, 155, 58}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=steerage....(trimmed)

***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=TKT Root CA 2, ...(trimmed)

*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 16285061615265061295479758192758299168932729034919494399422438099012833644130
  public y coord: 91712186275093768179410924600166089746856150468196826634149937267800342978949
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Cert Authorities:
<Empty>
*** ServerHelloDone
matching alias: john.k.doe.1258700011
matching alias: Card Authentication Certificate
matching alias: Authentication Certificate - John K. Doe
matching alias: Encryption Certificate - John K. Doe (Archived) - 12/4/2013
matching alias: doe_john_k@some.com
matching alias: Signing Certificate - John K. Doe
matching alias: Encryption Certificate - John K. Doe
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:106)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:85)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkForResponse(SynchronizationPoint.java:192)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWait(SynchronizationPoint.java:114)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWaitOrThrow(SynchronizationPoint.java:97)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:837)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:360)
    at pke4chat.TestProtoType.main(TestProtoType.java:87)
10:17:29 AM SENT (0): <presence id='c06He-3' type='unavailable'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='NfJ3flI83zSdUDzCEICtbypursw='/></presence>
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=John K. Doe, ...(trimmed)

***
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 183, 254, 13, 26, 104, 205, 105, 32, 193, 10, 62, 33, 82, 142, 4, 183, 231, 178, 204, 126, 170, 178, 111, 33, 155, 241, 187, 146, 182, 254, 138, 117, 145, 170, 80, 32, 176, 179, 113, 157, 193, 210, 75, 2, 195, 132, 111, 210, 183, 73, 98, 15, 201, 170, 127, 36, 15, 233, 126, 38, 225, 193, 6, 71 }
Smack Packet Reader (0), WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 5387
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: D3 5B D2 C9 4A AD 9A E6   F4 DE 3C 3C 0B D5 A2 C2  .[..J.....<<....
0010: CA A3 BA BE 2A 50 BA 27   3F 1E D1 34 94 CD 84 A4  ....*P.'?..4....
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 55 76 F5 74 04 B4 11 61   93 06 44 7C EA 28 9B 91  Uv.t...a..D..(..
0010: 84 1B A4 1D AF EF 8B 17   0E 85 A2 D7 2C DC F1 02  ............,...
Server Nonce:
0000: 55 76 F5 74 EE 3C 6C 05   68 BE DB 93 D7 BB C3 59  Uv.t.<l.h......Y
0010: 72 E0 A5 D5 8D 30 70 B0   81 2A 4E BE C4 77 8F 65  r....0p..*N..w.e
Master Secret:
0000: 61 9B 54 1F AB B0 F6 B1   D4 3C F9 79 0E D8 E1 AD  a.T......<.y....
0010: 29 3C E1 55 8D EF 2E 8D   13 3B 94 BB 32 5F C8 7F  )<.U.....;..2_..
0020: 13 A8 48 B6 C5 0F 50 A4   B5 41 82 C6 A3 F0 41 95  ..H...P..A....A.
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 42 1B F0 67 9E 1D 81 44   3A 76 8D D1 AD 4D 48 A4  B..g...D:v...MH.
0010: B6 27 70 12 08 FB CF 5D   39 7F 51 05 6D 08 61 F7  .'p....]9.Q.m.a.
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: DD 40 97 24 B0 96 00 A6   CD 49 02 7A 60 75 32 A2  .@.$.....I.z`u2.
0010: 80 41 FD 38 48 06 67 A7   51 E4 44 8E 72 AB 75 C4  .A.8H.g.Q.D.r.u.
Client write key:
0000: DE 5A B7 2D 9D 0F 2F C3   C9 82 D9 EA 88 0D 14 A3  .Z.-../.........
Server write key:
0000: A1 66 08 7C AB 23 56 B9   8F 09 2B 78 67 19 1F BF  .f...#V...+xg...
... no IV derived for this protocol
Jun 09, 2015 10:17:34 AM org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter shutdown
WARNING: shutdownDone was not marked as successful by the writer thread
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:106)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:85)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkForResponse(SynchronizationPoint.java:192)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWait(SynchronizationPoint.java:114)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.shutdown(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1265)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.shutdown(XMPPTCPConnection.java:494)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.shutdown(XMPPTCPConnection.java:476)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.disconnect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:666)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.disconnect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:646)
    at pke4chat.TestProtoType.main(TestProtoType.java:105)

main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
*** CertificateVerify
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
Smack Packet Reader (0), WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 264
Smack Packet Reader (0), WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 49, 187, 92, 176, 21, 132, 60, 183, 10, 47, 235, 93 }
***
Smack Packet Reader (0), WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 64
main, called closeSocket(true)
Smack Packet Writer (0), handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
Smack Packet Writer (0), called closeSocket()
Smack Packet Reader (0), handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

Comment: Post the output from running your client with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`. You can trim the certificate information.

Comment: A little more information is in order now.  I am back to my previous issue before posting about the handshake message sequence violation.  My client API code times out during the handshake. I have been stuck on one or the other. Things to note:
(1) If I force the selection of a smartcard cred in Windows-MY store it always times out.
(2) If I force the selection of a softtoken cred in Windows-MY store the connection completes and disconnects cleanly.
(3) If I present dialog to select any cred (of smartcard) it always times out. Softtoken is OK.
(4) My server was sending the CA list at one time.

Comment: Hmm, another observation. If I take my time in selecting the softtoken, it will timeout, as well. It is as though the handshake thread does not block on the selection of a credential.  Shouldn't it or is there a way to get it to do so? This seems like the opportunity for sequence violations.

Comment: This looks like you have two threads using the same socket.

Comment: That would explain the timeouts and handshake violations.  I will look into what might cause that.  What about the CA list of the certificate request? The openfire server uses a truststore for authenticating server to server and  a client truststore for client to server.  What would JSSE default to? My client and server are running on the same machine but I can't see why that would cause a problem.

Comment: JSSE defaults to the `lib/security/cacerts` truststore that comes with it.

Comment: Okay, so I knew that was the default for trust and authentication. I have it overridden with a jssecacerts file (identical to my client truststore).  On a side note, it seems JSSE suffers therefore from the same "spec bug" as Microsoft's stack. Implementations that do this correctly provide a separate way to define CA authorization space from those CA's used to perform chain authentication, which must include root CA's.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience this exception happens when a client certificate has expired. You can verify your JKS client certificate by

```
keytool -list -keystore client.keystore.jks  -v
```

and check the the Valid from ... to ...

Comment: Did not work for me. Acctualy, I created my certificate.

Comment: @Anders: I was facing Similar issue, after reading your answer I noticed my certificate valid from next day, since my ntp was not configured properly.! Fixing ntp, and regenerating certs, resolve the my issue.! Thanks

Comment: expired certificate was not the case for me, maybe Extended Key Usages has to inclue clientAuth as suggested by @Deca

Answer (score 2):

I think, there is no general fix for this error. The best way is to start over and follow exactly steps mentioned in https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_ssl_ca.

I had have the same error. It was caused by my mistake - I missed alias in the last step when I registered signed CA request file. Below steps works for me.

```
    - name: Generate keystore certificate
      command: "keytool -genkey -keystore /home/vagrant/auth/kafka.client{{kafka_broker_id}}.keystore.jks -validity 365 -storepass clientpass -keypass clientpass -dname 'CN=broker{{kafka_broker_id}}' -alias client-broker{{kafka_broker_id}} -storetype pkcs12"

    # getting signed version of certicate - first step
    - name: Certification request certificate 
      command: "keytool -keystore /home/vagrant/auth/kafka.client{{kafka_broker_id}}.keystore.jks -certreq -file /home/vagrant/auth/client-cert-file-broker{{kafka_broker_id}} -alias client-broker{{kafka_broker_id}} -storepass clientpass -keypass clientpass"

    # output will be signed certificate of kafka broker
    - name: Generate keystore certificate
      command: "openssl x509 -req -CA /home/vagrant/ssl/ca-cert -CAkey /home/vagrant/ssl/ca-key -in /home/vagrant/auth/client-cert-file-broker{{kafka_broker_id}} -out /home/vagrant/auth/client-cert-signed-{{kafka_broker_id}} -days 365 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:serversecret"

    - name: Import public CA to client keystore
      command: "keytool -keystore /home/vagrant/auth/kafka.client{{kafka_broker_id}}.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file /home/vagrant/ssl/ca-cert -storepass clientpass -keypass clientpass -noprompt"

    - name: Import signed host certificate by CA to keystore.jks
      command: "keytool -keystore /home/vagrant/auth/kafka.client{{kafka_broker_id}}.keystore.jks -import -file /home/vagrant/auth/client-cert-signed-{{kafka_broker_id}} -alias client-broker{{kafka_broker_id}} -storepass clientpass -keypass clientpass -noprompt"
```

To make authentification works correctly you need to add truststore - could be used the one from Kafka broker.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs when the client certificate does not have clientAuth in extended key usage.

See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/84822
And for Java, how it might be implemented on the server you're talking to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509ExtendedTrustManager.html

Comment: Please provide more details in your answer.

Comment: I can confirm the error and the wrong ExtendedKeyUsage.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by signing the client certificate with a CA trust by the server. Check https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_ssl_ca, it explains how.

Answer (score -2):

I had this exact error today trying to set up Kafka. For me it was that I accidentally enabled ssl client auth: ssl.client.auth=required in kafka brokers. This is only used for when the client needs to auth towards the broker. So in this case the communication is established to the broker, broker sends cert but expects then the client cert. this is where it breaks.

**to solve, simply remove the line in /etc/kafka/server.properties: ssl.client.auth=required**

(unless of course you want to do client auth -- then you have to configure the keystore and password for the client cert)

Comment: I also have this problem in Kafka when ssl.client.auth=required is set. But, If you remove this line of config, you will take away the reason for using security in Kafka. So, there should be another way of solving this.

Comment: no. this is not about disabling ssl or security. if you enable ssl, the client will connect to server and communication is encrypted with server certificate. the client can also verify the auth of the server using the server certificate. If you do enable this parameter  "ssl.client.auth=required" then _additional_ checking takes place. the server will ask for a certificate from the client. if the client can't auth, the communication will not take place. this is the problem. if you want to enable this, then you need to give add the client certificate also to broker if not trusted

Comment: still, removing client auth is reducing security, depending on how secure you need to be. I for example can't switch of client.auth.