# Kafka SSL Authentication Issues for inter-broker communication

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I'm currently configuring Apache Kafka with SSL authentication and am coming across an error when starting the service. It appears that the broker starts up correctly(leader election etc seems to occur), but as soon as any cluster operations begin to take place, I get the error below continually in the logs.

```
    [2019-05-16 11:04:00,351] INFO [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=1] Failed authentication with XXXX/YYYY (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2019-05-16 11:04:00,351] DEBUG [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=1] Node 1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-05-16 11:04:00,351] DEBUG An authentication error occurred in broker-to-broker communication. (org.apache.kafka.clients.ManualMetadataUpdater)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 2
```

Tried recreating the key and trust stores, tried dropping SSL from the inter broker listener(this results in an ANONYMOUS principal that I don't want to grant access to any resource).

To explain my configuration:

- Running Kafka 2.2 using the SSL principal builder
- I have 3 listeners setup - one on a public interface, and two on private interfaces(one for inter-broker comms and one for internal consumers)
- SSL is enabled on all 3 listeners
- Each listener is tied to it's own key and trust stores(as I need to be able to present different certificates for the internal addresses, as well as being able to trust different signing CA's), and SSL key password is provided for each key/keystore.
- Certificates were created using a locally generated key, local CSR generated then signed by a CA running on CFSSL multiroot.
- Keystores were then created using the key(same password), signed certificate and CA certificate imported.
- Truststore was created and certificate issuing CA(s) added here.

```
#Kafka Server Properties Configuration
#Broker and listener configuration
broker.id=1
listeners=egress://address1:9093,inter://address1:9094,ingest://address2:9092
advertised.listeners=egress://address1:9093,inter://address1:9094,ingest://address2:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=egress:SSL,inter:SSL,ingest:SSL
inter.broker.listener.name=inter
##
#Listener Trust and Keystore Configurations
#egress configuration
listener.name.egress.ssl.keystore.type=JKS
listener.name.egress.ssl.keystore.location=/data/kafka/pki/egress-keystore.jks
listener.name.egress.ssl.keystore.password=<redacted>
listener.name.egress.ssl.truststore.type=JKS
listener.name.egress.ssl.truststore.location=/data/kafka/pki/egress-truststore.jks
listener.name.egress.ssl.truststore.password=<redacted>
listener.name.egress.ssl.key.password=<redacted>
listener.name.egress.ssl.client.auth=required
listener.name.egress.ssl.principal.mapping.rules=RULE:^.*[Oo][Uu]=([a-zA-Z0-9.-]*).*$/$1/L,DEFAULT
##
#inter configuration
listener.name.inter.ssl.keystore.type=JKS
listener.name.inter.ssl.keystore.location=/data/kafka/pki/inter-keystore.jks
listener.name.inter.ssl.keystore.password=<redacted>
listener.name.inter.ssl.truststore.type=JKS
listener.name.inter.ssl.truststore.location=/data/kafka/pki/inter-truststore.jks
listener.name.inter.ssl.truststore.password=<redacted>
listener.name.inter.ssl.key.password=<redacted>
listener.name.inter.ssl.client.auth=requested
listener.name.inter.ssl.principal.mapping.rules=RULE:^.*[Oo][Uu]=([a-zA-Z0-9.-]*).*$/$1/L,DEFAULT
##
#ingest configuration
listener.name.ingest.ssl.keystore.type=JKS
listener.name.ingest.ssl.keystore.location=/data/kafka/pki/ingest-keystore.jks
listener.name.ingest.ssl.keystore.password=<redacted>
listener.name.ingest.ssl.truststore.type=JKS
listener.name.ingest.ssl.truststore.location=/data/kafka/pki/ingest-truststore.jks
listener.name.ingest.ssl.truststore.password=<redacted>
listener.name.ingest.ssl.key.password=<redacted>
listener.name.ingest.ssl.client.auth=required
listener.name.ingest.ssl.principal.mapping.rules=RULE:^.*[Oo][Uu]=([a-zA-Z0-9.-]*).*$/$1/L,DEFAULT
##

#Generic SSL Configuration
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.keystore.location=/data/kafka/pki/inter-keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=<redacted>
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.location=/data/kafka/pki/inter-truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=<redacted>
ssl.key.password=<redacted>
ssl.client.auth=requested
ssl.principal.mapping.rules=RULE:^.*[Oo][Uu]=([a-zA-Z0-9.-]*).*$/$1/L,DEFAULT
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false
super.users=User:<redacted>
##
#General configuration
auto.create.topics.enable=False
delete.topic.enable=True
log.dir=/var/log/kafka
log.retention.hours=24
log.cleaner.enable=True
log.cleanup.policy=delete
log.retention.check.interval.ms=3600000
min.insync.replicas=2
replication.factor=3
default.replication.factor=3
num.partitions=50
offsets.topic.num.partitions=50
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
transaction.state.log.num.partitions=50
num.replica.fetchers=4
auto.leader.rebalance.enable=True
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=60
transactional.id.expiration.ms=10000
unclean.leader.election.enable=False
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper:2180
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=100
controlled.shutdown.enable=True
broker.rack=rack1
```

Comment: Have you ensured the certificates are valid? See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50251363/6356

Comment: Certificates are valid. If I turn off authentication, but leave host verification on, everything appears to work... which implies that perhaps there's either an issue with the SSL principal mapping or simply that Kafka doesn't trust the issued certs perhaps? The trust store also looks fine though

Comment: I have this exact same issue, SSL is working fine, turn on ACLs and the client applications are authorized, but the nodes can't authorize between each other even with ClusterAction set

Answer (score 0):

Did you inserts the certificates to the keystores in the order you described? It could be important to first set the ca, then the certificate signed by the ca to get the chain of trust correctly.